# Creating Common/Reusable Logger Package in Python

Tags: python, logging, python-asyncio, datadog, python-logging

I am trying to build on top of the `logging` package in Python to create a reusable logger, so I don't have to rewrite boilerplate in every new file/package. I've hooked up my class to `Datadog`, and the API keys + base urls are in the environment variables now. This is my `logger.py`:

```
import logging
import os
import socket
from ts.common.logging.handler import DatadogCustomLogHandler



class LoggerFactory(object):

    _LOG = None

    @staticmethod
    def __create_logger(name: str, env: str, log_level: str):
        """
        Reusable logger. Sends logs to datadog if env variable is set to Production or UAT.

        :param name: Name of the logger
        :param log_level: Severity of log. Default is INFO
        :param env: Set to None for logging in local environment, Production or UAT sends logs to datadog
        :return: logger
        """

        LoggerFactory._LOG = logging.getLogger(name)
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

        if log_level == "INFO":

            LoggerFactory._LOG.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        elif log_level == "ERROR":

            LoggerFactory._LOG.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

        elif log_level == "DEBUG":

            LoggerFactory._LOG.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        if env == "UAT" or env == "Production":
            tags = f'service: {name}, host: {socket.gethostname()}, environment: {env}'
            dd_custom_handler = DatadogCustomLogHandler(tags=tags, service=name, level=log_level)
            LoggerFactory._LOG.addHandler(dd_custom_handler)
            return LoggerFactory._LOG
        else:
            return LoggerFactory._LOG

    @staticmethod
    def get_logger(name: str = __name__, env: str = "UAT", log_level: str = logging.INFO):
        logger = LoggerFactory.__create_logger(name, env, log_level)
        return logger
```

Now the question I have is, this is fine to log messages under a single name if only a single function is running in a `main()` function - I can call the logger for instance via

```
logger = LoggerFactory.get_logger("main.logger")
```

for instance. However, if there are other functions within `main()`, they don't inherit the same name `"main.logger"`. I will have to call them separately in each module or file via `get_logger("child.logger")`, `get_logger("nested.logger")`, etc.

How do I ensure that the reusable logger persists its name across logs from several different packages? Also, will this be fine to use in `async` functions?

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times [Python Logging Taking Much Longer Than Print for Async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76103803/python-logging-taking-much-longer-than-print-for-async)